# Calculate variance of a proportion using a confidence interval and point estimate

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, variance

I'd like to know how to compute the variance of a proportion using the point estimate and confidence interval. In this case, I'm referring to data from a 2 x 2 table: Sensitivity = 0.88 (95% CI, 0.77 to 0.95). Is it possible to estimate the variance of the sensitivity (0.88) given that confidence interval? If not, what other information do I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the CI was estimated using a normal approximation:
The formula for a binomial proportion confidence interval is

[image]

So from this you can reverse the equation and get the SD out.